# Uploading a data set from Excel 2016 into R the Date heading changes to general format

Tags: r

I am reading an Excel workbook, which contains one sheet "MO" and the header in B2 has a date, when loaded into R the date format is changed to general format. e.g 2016-11-26 is changed to 42700.

How can change it to show the correct date format instead of the general format type when loaded into R.

Here is the sample image of the uploaded Excel worksheet into R:
[image: The R uploaded data]

And here is the data in Excel:
[image: the Excel data]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always set the Header argument to false...

```
 library(XCLConnect)
df<-readWorksheet(object, sheet, header=FALSE )

#  or :

df<-readWorksheet(file.choose(),header=FALSE)
```

I never used the XCLConnect package because its not available (for R version 3.6.2). generally speaking it is better to use a file path to read in your desired file rather than the file.choose() function.

For example:

your file is called "file.xlsx" and lives in a directory (Folder) named "Documents", you want to read a specific sheet called "MO" of this file into R by using your desired method (like readWorksheet() ) but you dont want to create an automatic header because it has a date in it.  So you proceed as followed:

```
# 1 : load your needed package i.e "XCLConnect"

library(XCLConnect)

# 2 use a function to read in your file

df<-readWorksheet(object= "user/home/Documents/file.xlsx", sheet= "MO", header=FALSE)

# Attention here: in windows file paths are build with" \ "instead of "/"
# so you filepath would be "user\home\Documents\file.xlsx"
# 3 View your document to see if everything is the way you want it

View(df)

#4 finally you can transform your Date Row by using:

df[1,]<- as.Date(df[1,], format= "%Y-%m-%d")
```

Or with the xlsx- package

```
install.packages("xlsx")
library(xlsx)
df<-read.xlsx(file,  header=FALSE)
```

or read.csv

```
df<-read.csv(file, header =FALSE)

## then use:

df[1,]<- as.Date(df[1,])
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested and here the result I am getting:
> library(xlsx)
> def <- read.xlsx("EMT1357-Mo.xlsx", sheetName = "Mo", header=FALSE)
Error in .jcall(cell, "I", "getCellType") : 
  method getCellType with signature ()I not found

Comment: ok, i am not sure what causes this, how do you normally load it in, when you get the false date header?

Comment: This is the way I use to upload:
library(XCLConnect)

Comment: do you use the function "readWorksheet()" it also accepts the arg :  "header = FALSE"

Comment: This is the way I use to upload:
library(XCLConnect)
library(xlsx)
def <- readxl::read.xlsx(file.choose())
# then I select the file and the process is done and when I check using view(def)
# I get what is shown in the first picture

Comment: ok no problem updated the answer to your case: just do:" def <-read.xlsx(file.choose(), header =F) " and you should be fine

Comment: How would you use the readWorksheet()? need a sample. thanks for your feedback by the way.

Comment: I tried:
def <-read.xlsx(file.choose(), sheetName = "Mo", header =F)
# I get:
Error in .jcall(cell, "I", "getCellType") : 
  method getCellType with signature ()I not found
>

Comment: naturally i would not advise to use the file.choose() function, rather give a file path to the read funcion, i will edit my answer to make it more clear

Comment: Thanks it worked, I sued the following:
def <- read.xlsx("C:/Users/Hussein/Documents/Test/EMT1357-Mo.xlsx", sheetIndex = 1, header=FALSE)

Comment: How do you close the subject?

Comment: To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.